# Individual track info on SCM music player

Tags: javascript, audio-player

Warning: while I'm at ease with HTML + CSS, I know very little JS. Please forgive me for being ignorant on these matters...

I've just implemented a nice open-source, JS-based radio on our Wordpress website: SCM Music Player (see https://github.com/cshum/SCM-Music-Player). Among other qualities, it enables one to browse around on the site while streaming.

See: [www.meridian-online.com](http://www.meridian-online.com)

This radio is meant to enhance the browsing experience of our website, but also to give an introduction to the various artists who composed the music being played. Therefore, what I'd like to do is 'add' an extra piece of info to each track: a link to a page on our website presenting the musician, the contents of the track, etc.

For example, when the track "Transfiguration" is being played, I would like the music player to include a link to the [page discussing this track](http://www.meridian-online.com/arcoverde-cordel-do-fogo-encantado/).

Now I've included to the player a hard-coded link to the page presenting *all* of the available tracks (http://www.meridian-online.com/mmm/); but I don't know how to replace this by a customized link that would directly lead to the post discussing the song.

Right now, the player works this way: in the header of my Wordpress theme, I must add a snippet of code, including the names + URL of each music file (`{'title':'Transfiguracão - by Cordel do Fogo Encantado','url':'https://soundcloud.com/meridian-online/transfigurac-o-cordel-do-fogo'}` etc.).

I suppose I would have to find a way to add an extra bit of metadata for each track — namely, the URL to the explanatory page. But I don't know how to modify the JS files accordingly.

Any advice on how to handle this?
(I've written the plugin developer, but after many weeks, still no reply)

Cheers,

Dorian